# JQuery IE11 radio button selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-11

Using the following code

```
$(".submitButton").click(function(event){
  if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  if (!$(this).hasClass("disabled")){
    $('.invoice-form').find(':input').prop("disabled",false);
    $(".invoiceDate").prop("disabled",true);
    //event.preventDefault();
    //return false;
  }
});
```

In IE11, when submitting a form, all elements are being enabled, except the radio buttons.

Any ideas on this one? We need the radio buttons to be reenabled so the proper value is set. It functions as expected in non-IE browsers.

Comment: try to write it as below if($(this).hasClass("disabled)){your code}else{} instead of  if (!$(this)){}

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I go down the Bootstrap route when I create my forms.

HTML/Bootstrap

```
<div class="radio">
<label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
<label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2</label>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
<i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to write it as below

```
if($(this).hasClass("disabled)){your code}else{}
```

instead of

```
if (!$(this)){}
```

if you want pure java script use the below to disable the whole form[javascript usually is more compatible and friendly to browsers

```
var fields = document.getElementById("YOURDIVID").getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
{
    fields[i].disabled = true;
}
```

if you insist on jquery use the below 
For jquery 1.6+, use .prop() instead of .attr()

```
$("#parent-selector :input").prop("disabled", true);
```

or

```
$("#parent-selector :input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

or

```
$('#mydivform').find('input, textarea, button, select').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

`:input` selects all `<input>, <select>, <textarea> and <button>` elements. Also the attribute is readonly, if you use disabled to the elements they won't be posted to the server, so make sure you disable them onsubmit.